# How to show the reduced cone is homeomorphic to $D^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The reduced cone is given by:
$$CX = （X \times I） /(X \times 1 ∪ x_0 × I),$$
where $I$ is the unit interval $[0,1], x_0$ is the base point.
Let $x_0$ be any point in $S^1$. How can I show that $CS^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$? 
$S^1$ is the unit circle and $D^2$ is the unit disk.

I proved that the unreduced cone is homeomorphic to $D^2$, so I started this problem with showing a unit disk with equivalent relation on a radius is homeomorphic with $D^2$. But I cannot find a proper bijection between them. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the map $f:X\times I\to D^2$ defined by $f(x,t)=(1-t)x+tx_0$ (continuous and surjective).

You can show that $f(X\times I\cup x_0\times I)=\{x_0\}$.

also $f(x,t)=f(y,s)$ iff $(x,t),(y,s)\in X\times I\cup x_0\times I$.

The set $X\times I\cup x_0\times I$ is compact.

Comment: thanks so much, I understand now!